# ClearCase CCRC: list folders under source control / a VOB?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I want to list folders under source control. What is the CCRC command line command to list folders recursively? Can I do it without creating a view first and therefore updating all files / folders locally? That is, can I get folder list - using rcleartool command line - directly from Clear Case source control w/o creating a view first / or updating local folder first?

What is rcleartool command line command to list folders under Source Control / VOB? I need to list folders (like svn list  does) under a VOB? That is, directly from VOB w/o creating a local view first

Answer (score 1):

**[`rcleartool`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929)** (like cleartool) would need a view to be able to list folders, since those folders depends on what you have selected (i.e. on the config spec of the view)